# Чтение разнотипных переменных при помощи ReadLn

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат. 16 строка

```
Type result = record
  Sur: string [15]; //Фамилия
  Rus: 2..5;        //Оценка по русскому
  Alg: 2..5;        //Оценка по алгебре
  Phis: 2..5;       //Оценка по физике
end;
var list: array[1..4] of result; //Массив записей
    F1, F2: Text;
begin
  assign(F1, 'C:\PABCWork.NET\Символы и строки\10a.txt'); //Связывание с файлом 10_a.txt
  assign(F2, 'Best.txt'); //Связывание с файлом Best.txt
  reset(F1);              //Открытие файла F1 для чтения
  rewrite(F2);            //Открытие файла F2 для записи
  readln(F1);             //Пропуск 1 срок в файле F1
  for i: integer :=1 to 4 do  //Цикл ввода из файла F1
    readln(F1, list[i].Sur, list[i].Alg, list[i].Phis);
  writeln('Список отличников');
  for i: integer :=1 to 4 do  //Цикл отбора отличников и вывода их фамилий
    if (list[i].Rus = 5) and (list[i].Alg=5) and (list[i].Phis=5) then
      writeln (list[i].Sur);  //Вывод фамилии на экран
end.


Содержимое файла 10a:
Таблица успеваемости 10 "А" класс
Смирнов 4 4 3
Скляров 5 5 5
Филатов 5 5 5
Мальченко 5 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Множественное чтение переменных при помощи `ReadLn` хорошо работает для чисел, так как разделителем для них является пробел. Но для строк это не работает, т.к. для них пробел это обычный символ. То есть сколько бы не было написано переменных в `ReadLn`, если первая имеет тип `string`, то все вся строка будет считана в нее, поэтому и возникает ошибка.

Если есть возможность надо изменить формат файл, чтобы числа шли впереди

```
Таблица успеваемости 10 "А" класс
4 4 3 Смирнов
5 5 5 Скляров
5 5 5 Филатов
5 4 5 Мальченко
```

Или надо изменить способ считывания переменных, и получать строку до первого пробела

```
function ReadName: string;
var
  c: Char;
begin
  Result := '';
  repeat
    Read(F1, c);
    Result := Result + c;
  until c = ' ';
end;
...
list[i].Sur := ReadName;
readln(F1, list[i].Rus, list[i].Alg, list[i].Phis);
```